# Условие для date (время)

Tags: дата, php

Как задать условие, чтобы с 08:00 до 24:00 скрипт показывает один текст, после 24:00 и до 08:00 показывает другой текст?

Благодарю за внимание!

```
if(date('H') >= 8 && date('H') <= 24){
  echo "Сейчас работает";
} else {
  echo "Сейчас закрыто";
}
```

Мой вариант кода не срабатывает :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `G Часы в 24-часовом формате без ведущего нуля от 0 до 23`

[`function.date.php`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

```
$date = intval(date('G'));
if ($date >= 8 && $date <= 23) {
  echo "Сейчас работает";
} else {
  echo "Сейчас закрыто";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам!